# MS ACCESS - How to filter a subform datasheet by a main form's textbox like a searchbox

Tags: ms-access, filtering, subform, datasheet

I have a main form1 (formview) and a subform2 (datasheetview) based on the same query like a splitform.

In the main form1 i have a textbox that i want to use like a searchbox for the subform2.

This searchbox has to filter the subform2 datasheet by searching in 3 different fields (name, type, number) and when finding a record that matches the searchbox's value, it has to filter the datasheet by this value.

I tried with macro Applyfilter and VBA but didn't succed..
Can someone help me?

Comment: Review https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/how-to-create-your-own-split-form-in-access-using-vba/

Comment: i need a searchbox feature, i know how to do a pseudo-splitform and i used that way you linked.. but now i need a searchbox..

Comment: Should edit question to show attempted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Private Sub tbxSearch_AfterUpdate()
Me.ctrDS.Form.Filter = "Member_name LIKE '*" & Me.tbxSearch & "*' OR TypeOfBusiness LIKE '*" & Me.tbxSearch & "*' OR Member_ContactNumber='" & Me.tbxSearch & "'"
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Or

```
Private Sub tbxSearch_AfterUpdate()
With Me.ctrDS.Form.RecordsetClone
    .FindFirst "Member_name LIKE '*" & Me.tbxSearch & "*' OR TypeOfBusiness LIKE '*" & Me.tbxSearch & "*' OR Member_ContactNumber='" & Me.tbxSearch & "'"
    If Not .NoMatch Then Me.ctrDS.Form.Bookmark = .Bookmark
End With
End Sub
```